# How to deconstruct and reply to a 3 worded sentence

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to write code that would take a three worded sentence compromising of a pronoun, subject (noun), and verb. Ex: I hate you. Then it would identify each word (wether it is a noun, verb, or pronoun) and remember the noun and verb. It would then reply to the sentence in a very obvious manner such as;
Input: I hate apples.
Reply: Why do you hate apples?
Input: I play sports.
Reply: Why do you play sports?

Pretty simple stuff, but I am having trouble taking apart each word in the sentence and then saving each word for which type they are. I will deal with proper nouns later, for now I am dealing wiht a simple list of about 2000 nouns.

```
from nouns import nouns_list
from adjectives import adjectives_list
from verbs import verbs_list
from adverbs import adverbs_list
from pronouns import pronouns_list



test = raw_input("Please input a fruit: ")

words = test.split()
    #numbers = map(int, test.split())
    #use later!


def word_identify(words):
    for word in words:
        if word in nouns_list:
            print words + " is a noun!"
            word == noun
        elif words in verbs_list:
            print words + " is a verb!"
            word == verb
        elif words in pronouns_list:
            print words + " is a pronoun!"
            word == pronoun
        elif words in adjectives_list:
            print words + " is an adjective!"
            word == adjective
        elif words in adverbs_list:
            print word + " is a adverb!"
            word == adverb
        elif words == 'i' or words == "I":
            print "This is the I pronoun!"
            word == 'you'
        else:
            print "Word " + words + " not identified!"
            return -1
        return 1

while word_identify(test) > 0:
    test = raw_input("Please input a fruit: ")
```

At the end I will just ad a simple print "Why" + verb + noun + '?'
Basically I am asking how do I properly use the .split() function and how do I remember which if the specific word got triggered with? The fact that it will return a verb in an improper tense is fine by me, I will deal with that later! 
Many thanks
Braam

Edit: Ignore the `numbers = map(int, test.split())`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `==` operator, you are comparing the two objects. So, `word == adverb` returns `True` or `False` depending on if the objects are equal. Instead try this:

```
def word_identify(words):
    parts_of_speech = []
    for word in words:
        if word in nouns_list:
            print word + " is a noun!"
            part_of_speech = 'noun'
        elif words in verbs_list:
            print word + " is a verb!"
            part_of_speech = 'verb'
        ...
        else:
            print "Word " + word + " not identified!"
            part_of_speech = None
        parts_of_speech.append(part_of_speech)
    return parts_of_speech
```

Then, `word_identify()` will return a list similar to this:

```
['pronoun', 'verb', 'noun']
```

And if it can't identify a word:

```
['pronoun', None, 'noun']
```

Comment: that was very helpful! The only problem is that now it is not outputting anything! I looked over the code and I cannot figure out why because print functions do exists.

Comment: You'll have to post some code, otherwise we can't see the problem.

Comment: Please choose an answer to mark as correct if your question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
d = {'noun':nouns_list, 
     'pronoun':pronouns_list,
     'adjective':adjectives_list,
     'verb':verbs_list,
     'adverb':adverbs_list
}

def part_of_speech(word):
    for pos,l in d.items():
        if word in l:
            return pos
    return None

def get_parts_of_speech(sentence):
    return [part_of_speech(word.lower()) for word in sentence.split()]

sentence = raw_input("Enter a three word sentence [<noun> <verb> <pronoun>]:");

print "The parts are:", get_parts_of_speech(sentence)
```